Three.js load texture using the MTLLoader in Electron
I am currently working on an Electron application with Three.js to display 3D models that can be selected via a file dialog
dialog from the file system.
I have managed to load and display the model using fs.readFileSync and OBJLoader.parse, but I am currently missing the texture, which is in MTL format.
I have seen that the MTLLoader also has a parse function, but how can I load the individual images that are defined in the MTL file?
Here is an abstract version of my code right now:
const objFilePath = "./model.obj"
const mtlFilePath = "./model.mtl"

const objContent = fs.readFileSync(objFilePath)
const mtlContent = fs.readFileSync(mtlFilePath)

/* sending content from main to renderer ... */

const objLoader = new OBJLoader();
const model = objLoader.parse(objContent);

// const mtlLoader = new MTLLoader();
// const model = mtlLoader.parse(mtlContent, "");
// ...
    
scene.add(model)

Thanks, Ypselon.
